# Unity2D: ForceMode2D.Impulse dragging player back

Tags: c#, 2d

I have a script attached to a tagged object that pushes my player on trigger. It works perfectly, however my player (after collision) gets dragged back to the tagged object and continues bouncing. How would I stop this. All I want is for my player to get pushed back by the tagged object for a short amount of distance and stay there. Could anyone help me with this?

This is my script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if (other.tag == "Bouncy object")
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * 15, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: `unity` is not `unity3d`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a vector in your AddForce() method rather than affecting the transform directly:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if (other.tag == "Bouncy object")
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(15, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```